# How to find equivalent resistance and equipotential points in these types of circuits

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6thV.jpg)
we're supposed to find equivalent ressistance between A and B

1. Where to START the circuit simplification in these types of question where all the resistors are parallel to one another?
2. Where should the affective resistance( for example, of the 2 circled resistors) be, when the origin of each resistor are 2 different nodes
   I tried to find the equivalent resistance between the 2 circled resistors (in above citcuit) for a start.
   But i dunno where to put the affective resistance coz both of their origins are at 2 "different" nodes.
3. Can we cancel any branches in this circuit?
   How to identify where the potentials are equal when ALL the resistors are "parallel" to each other as in the above circuit. 
   I know potentials are equal if they are parallel and symmetrical to one another.
   but when exactly does the potential become equal (in this circuit ) so that we can cancel that node and branch and say that no current travels through it?

Comment: Try to find symmetry and equipotential points

Comment: Looks like a tough one to me.  If you know circuit analysis you write a bunch of linear algebra equations and then eliminate.  Many times there are short cuts due to the symmetry ... but I don't see it yet .. so back to the equations.

Comment: Hi oh nameless one and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: This is not a worked example. Its a homework question and  I've specified my doubt in this (after editing). I know the answer but what I want is where the affective resistor should be placed when 2 resistors are of different nodes and where the equipotential points of this circuit are...

Comment: You can redraw this as like 3 spokes in a wheel and you see that all 3 paths that start at A and go to B are identical. If total circuit current was 3 amps, then 1 amp per starting resistor at A ... then each branch gets 0.5A and then .... the final resistors at B each get 2 times 0.5A ... so it's back to the 3amps we started with.  If R=1 and we have the 1 amp in per branch then its a 2.5v drop from A to B.  Since total current is 3A and V=2.5, then R final is =2.5/3.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a real answer, but is more than a comment.

Follow these steps:

1. Are there some points you're certain by symmetry to be at the same potential?
2. Once found these points, you can safely connect them with a wire without altering the currents.
3. It there are resistors placed in parallel, replace them by one equivalent resistor.